# \makechapterstyle{} for scrreprt (change chapter title format)

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

The memoir-class offers the command \makechapterstyle{} to define the look of all chapter titles (e.g. https://www.writelatex.com/1312879nbdvry#/3224717/)

Is there a way to create something similar with the scrreprt-class?
[image: Example form Bristol university]

Comment: `\chapterformat` comes to mind, along with `\setkomafont` and using `chapterprefix`, `chapter` and `chapterentry` as arguments

Comment: Hi @harry, seems we never heard back from you. Are you still interested in solving the issue or can we close this question.