# Formatting and Styling of Headers using titlesec in scrbook-class

Tags: formatting, titlesec, scrbook

I'm trying to write a book in LaTeX with `scrbook` class. I'm not that experienced in typography with TeX, nevertheless I would like to give my chapter-headings a special style. I found a very nice style here: http://www.bradleymedia.org/latex-chapter-headings.

I was able to reproduce the style in my document, but I couldn't add some coloring and spacing I would like the header to have. My question is now, how to add a specific color to the "chapter", the chapter number, the line on the right side and the chapter title?

The code I would like to use for this is: (I hope this minimal example works :D)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphics}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \color{blue}\rule{15cm}{1.2cm} } }
    {10pt}{\Huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test-chapter}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I found an option to change the color of the line on the left. But I don't know how to change the color of the other elements in this header.

(Another small problem: A warning-message occurs when I use `titlesec` with KOMA `scrbook`).

Thanks to everyone who an help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Indeed, `titlesec` and KOMA classes are not fully compatible.

Comment: Thank you, do you know a better option? At the time the formatting is working and does not produce any further errors. Thus I decided to stick along with this package. Can you help me to find a possibility to change the colors as I wrote above?

Comment: The better option is to use the commands provided by KOMA rather than a package which breaks KOMA. See Sveinung's comment below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a suggestion without `titlesec`. Note, that the code needs KOMA-Script version 3.15 or newer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{chaptercolor}{blue!80!black}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\color{chaptercolor}\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{}}%
  \rlap{\enskip\resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \rule{15cm}{1.2cm} }%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=30pt,afterskip=20pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\vspace{10pt}}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With an older KOMA-Script Version you can try the following code to get a similar result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{chaptercolor}{blue!80!black}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\color{chaptercolor}\Huge\raggedleft}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \makebox[\linewidth][r]{\MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{}}}%
  \rlap{\enskip\resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \rule{15cm}{1.2cm} }%
}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{20pt}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace{20pt}}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Unfortunately I don't use Version 3.15 but an older version. Would it be possible to rearrange your example to make it compatible with older KOMA-Script-Versions?

Comment: I found another interesting layout on Stack-Exchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194163/makechapterstyle-for-scrreprt-change-chapter-title-format. The thread is closed but I would be interested to find a solution to create this layout for the scrbook-class.

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? The current version on CTAN and in TeX Live is 3.16. In MiKTeX it is 3.15. I have added an example that should work with an older version.

Comment: Thank you for the second example, esdd! It works very well and it's operating characteristics do not collide with any KOMA-class features. I downloaded MikTeX about one year ago and did no updates. I dont really know which KOMA-Script version I use, but I suggest it is a really old one :D. Thanks again for your quick and well done help! Arne H.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to achieve the coloring of all elements:
I just added \color{myblue} with a predefined color to the settings of the fonts.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft\color{myblue}}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \color{myblue}\rule{15cm}{1.2cm} } }
{10pt}{\Huge}
```

The next formatting thing I would like to apply is a smaller distance from the heading to the top of the page. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help again!

Comment: If you are using KOMA-Script, why are you not using the very advanced build in formatting commands. `setkomafont`, `addtokomafont` etc. As you will see from the manual, `titlesec`is not compatible. Colouring all heading: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{myblue}}`

Comment: @Sveinung: Thanks for your answer. As I wrote above I am not that experienced in using TeX. Could you provide a minimal example which shows that it would be possible to achieve the same result for the chapter headings with "setkomafont" etc?