# Error in chapter Style modification

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, titles, tikz-styles, document-classes

for the past few days, I have been attempting to change the chapter style, but I've encountered an error with the class I am using. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extra/MyThesis}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}
%define new chapter style (just for a nicer look)
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%

\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\itshape\color{yourcolor}}
\settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\hfill\color{yourcolor}\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]

\node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]
\hrule height 1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
{\chaptitlefont ##1}}
}
%use new chapter style
\chapterstyle{mystyle}


%\linespread{1.25}
%\setlength{\parskip}{16pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
%print minitoc
%\printmyminitoc
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2}
\section{test}
\section{abc}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
%print minitoc
%\printmyminitoc
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The code for the .clc class:

```
\ProvidesClass{latex/MyThesis_}[2021/02/03 v1.0 MyThesis_ class]
\newif\ifCU@bookmode
\CU@bookmodetrue
\DeclareOption{report}{\CU@bookmodefalse}
\DeclareOption{book}{\CU@bookmodetrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifCU@bookmode
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}%
\ProcessOptions\relax%
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}%
\else%
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}%
\fi%
\else
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}%
\ProcessOptions\relax%
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
  \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}%
\else%
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}%
\fi%
\fi
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[square, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}%Added
\usepackage{blindtext}%Added
\sloppy 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
   \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}] }{%             A - Roman
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
     \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              R - Superscripts
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{{%             S - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{{%    X - Other Symbols
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}%              Z - Acronyms
                        {{}}}}}}}}}}
    \usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels, 
                 pdfpagelayout = useoutlines,
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
%%                 pagebackref,
                 colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 citecolor = red,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf}
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \graphicspath{{figures/}}
\ifpdf
\pdfpageheight=297mm
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\else
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\fi
%\setlength{\hoffset}{0.00cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1.00cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1.00cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
%\setlength{\textheight}{22cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\footskip}{1.36cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.86cm}
 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
    \fontsize{12pt}{7mm}\selectfont
   \loop{\scriptsize\the\@tempcnta}\\
    \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<25\repeat}}
\newif\ifdraft
\draftfalse
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\small \leftmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\ifdraft
 \fancyhead[L,L]{
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}
     \end{picture}}
\fi
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\ifdraft  
   \fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
     \end{picture}}
\fi}
\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{A thesis submitted for the degree of}}
\newcommand{\nth}{\textsuperscript{th}}
\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\collegeordept#1{\gdef\@collegeordept{#1}}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\crest#1{\gdef\@crest{#1}}
\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {\large \vspace*{18mm} {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{18mm}}
    {{\Large \@author} \par} \vspace*{8mm} {\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par} \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@university} \par} \vspace*{20mm}
    {{\submittedtext} \par} \vspace*{1ex}
    {\it {\@degree} \par} \vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}
\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{dedication}
{\begin{alwayssingle}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\LARGE }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{quote} \begin{center}}
{\end{center} \end{quote} \end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{acknowledgementslong}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{abstracts} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{abstractslong} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm} \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{abstractseparate} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1in}
 \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1ex} \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\it \submittedtext} \par}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}
\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}
```

I have an error of the form

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \makechapterstyle
```

I want to obtain a result like this in book class
[image]

Comment: putting that command into the search box on this site returns a first hit https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194163/makechapterstyle-for-scrreprt-change-chapter-title-format which tells you it's a command from the memoir class, but you are using book

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please tell me if I could use this code with the book class?

Comment: not really no, you can't really expect to grab some configuration code from a big class like memoir and copy the commands without their definitions and hope they work in another class.  also you should not be doing `  \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}%` avoid ever explicitly using `pdftex` or `dvips` options.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem now thank you very much, but how can I achieve a similar result with my class?

Comment: I have no idea what result you want, you don't say, and just posted dozens of lines of code that have no effect, you need to say in words what design you want

Comment: I edit my question and I add the style what I want, but this style does not march in book class, this is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by `titlesec` package. More details you can take a look at [this](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). Not too sure what is your expected style of unnumbered chapter title (e.g., Contents, List of Figures, etc.). I assume they will be just a horizontal rule with title underneath. Here is an example with book class. It will be also working in your case I believe.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\color{yourcolor}}%%This is the format code applied to the whole heading (label+title)
{\flushright\sffamily\Huge\textbf{\chaptername}\space%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\textbf{\thechapter}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%%The chapter label is defined in here
{0pt}%%This is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length (it must not be empty)
{\vspace{1.5ex}\hrule height 1.5pt \vspace{1em}\itshape\huge\sffamily}%%This is the code preceding the title body
[]%%This is the code following the title body

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2}
\section{test}
\section{abc}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I truly appreciate your response; it is very helpful to me.

Comment: @Espoir you’re welcome. I am glad this is helpful.